# Stored Proc returns all in code, but single row when fired manually

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, sqldataadapter

I have never used ADO.NET.
I have a stored proc that takes a student number and returns a single student, if I exec manually.

If I execute it in my code, it returns all 6000 students. What is different about executing in code?

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["My_DB"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sk.My_StoredProc", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    //Add Parameter values
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = studentNumber;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentNameFragment", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = studentNameFragment;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SchoolYear", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.schoolYr;

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
```

Comment: perhaps the parameter values are not setted properly(in C# code), or maybe! the code which you executed manually you executed it on difference DB, can you show the stored procedure code and also where you setting the assigned values for the parameters in C# code? aslo try to `remove cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` at there

Answer (score 0):

Try using a SqlDataReader rather than ExecuteNonQuery as shown below:

```
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
```

ExecuteReader will allow you to read the result set from your SQLCommand.

ExecuteNonQuery will only return an integer value representing the number of rows in your DB affected by the command.

Comment: I finally got around to giving this a try, it gives me an error, "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

Comment: I suspect that you are opening the connection twice or more.  Make sure the con.Open(); only appears once.  Can you post your latest edits to this code?

Comment: The code is currently unchanged from OP.  I should need to specifically close the connection because of the 'using' statements, right?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the second parameter 'StudentNameFragment' was being passed as an empty string instead of null, so it was returning everything.

Answer (score -2):

ExecuteNonQuery - isn't really supposed to be used with SELECT  - only update, insert or delete.  And it doesn't return rows...according to MSDN - see link below

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: you are correct - i am a new member and this was my first answer - or should i say comment - i see how it works now.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can delete this "question" and the negative points will be removed.